# Symfony 4.1 KernelTestCase Repository ConnectionException

Tags: doctrine, phpunit, symfony4, connectionexception

I'm following the symfony docs (https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/doctrine.html) trying to test my repository classes against my MySQL database.
The relevant code part is this:

```
class ProductRepositoryTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }

    public function testSearchByCategoryName()
    {
        $products = $this->entityManager
            ->getRepository(Product::class)
            ->searchByCategoryName('foo')
        ;

        $this->assertCount(1, $products);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->entityManager->close();
        $this->entityManager = null; // avoid memory leaks
    }
}
```

When I execute the testclass with PhpUnit I get a Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException with the message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

I stored my database connection data in the DATABASE_URL in the .env file and the connection works fine when executing: bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate

But it seems this configuration is not used for testing (because 'NO' is not my password in the .env file). Do I have to store the connection configuration in another file for testing? And if yes, where do I have to store the configuration, so that it gets used in my testcase?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.env` file is only used in `dev` environment. If you're in `prod` or in `test`, it's not even read: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#the-env-file-environment-variables. It's clear in some parts of the doc, but less in some others, which can be confusing.

---

In your case, you can check your `config` folder, more specifically probably under `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` and `config/packages/parameters.yaml`, and see how the `DATABASE_URL` is used (when it exists). From there, you can either hardcode that URL in config files specific to the `test` environment (creating a `test` subfolder under `config/packages` for instance), or you can give the proper `DATABASE_URL` environment variable to `phpunit` "manually" by using `APP_ENV=... && bin/phpunit ...`.

Here's what a solution would look like in the first scenario :

```
# config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
  dbal:
    url: 'mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name'
```

Comment: I just tried it and it worked perfectly, thank you very much!! :)